# How to make the flexbox uniform?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have my CSS like this.There is an unnecesary space appearing in the last row. How to make the flex box Uniform. products1 is the outermost div, catlist1 is the middle one and d1 is the innermost div:-

```
 .products1{
        position:absolute;
        top:800px;
        padding:50px;
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display:flex;
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 90%;
    }

    .catlist1{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 100%;    
        padding:0px;
        display:flex;
    }

    .d1{
        display: block;
        background:white;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-size: cover; 
        margin: 10px auto;
        width:100px;
        height:25px;
        border:0 solid #dee0e2;
        display: inline;
        padding:50px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
```

And I am getting the output as this:-
[![This][1]][1]

HTml:-

```
<div class="products1">
   <div class="catlist1">
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
     <div class="d1"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML code also?

Comment: added sample html @Umbo

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't get wether you need a grid with 4 elements per line or if the elements should wrap depending on the available space. Also, is the number of `.d1` items fixed or variable?

Comment: All I want is inner divs should have 
1.fixed width, and yes 4 elements per line
2.d1 items is variable.The HTML provided is just to give a rough idea @Umbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change Margin property of d1 class as follows:

```
.d1 {
        display: block;
        background:white;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        background-size: cover; 
        **margin: 10px;**
        width:100px;
        height:25px;
        border:0 solid #dee0e2;
        display: inline;
        padding:50px;
        text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 1px 5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

As `margin:10px auto;` leads to the left and right margin of each `flex-item` to auto which leads to uneven left/right margin distribution at last row where number of items is less.

Answer (score 1):

Out the distance from the auto mode    `margin: 10px auto;`  to `margin: 3px 3px;`

But if you want more precision , use `@media screen and`

you will have
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the `auto` in your `margin` statement for `d1`. It centers the element it is applied to, thus it spaces the elements in the last row evenly.

If you want to keep the `auto` *and* have the last line appear as the others, then I don't think that's possible without JavaScript or switching to `display: grid` and media queries for different widths. If you just want to fill the last line and find a different solution for the margins, then add another `div` with a CSS rule `flex-grow: 1` to the end of the catlist `div`.